# Issue with a products database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a problem concerning the correct design of a relationship. My database has only one table called `products`, which has the following columns:

```
id, name, categories, price, description, extra data
```

And I need to display the info of categories but the problem is this:

I have the categories saved as one string all together.

- category1, category2, category3, category4

I understand I need to create the relationship-table but I don't see how to call the info.

For example, if I create

```
table: relcat
iditem (from table products)
idcategory (from table category)
```

then how do I move the values from the column `categories` from table `products` to the table `categories`?

Comment: You must create link table (product_ID, category). It allows you to create foreign key constraints. The `category` field will be removed from table's structure at all, of course.

Comment: Look up first normal form.  In particular look up why keyed access to all data is a good thing.  From keyed access, move on to indexed access.  If you have several thousand products,  your searches will take seconds if you have keyed and indexed access,  and will take an hour if you do table scans.

Comment: It is better to have as separate table for categories.  But if you must have a commalist, see `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK; you've discovered that having multiple data values in a single field is a Bad Idea.  Good.  Let's move on.

You need a second table to hold the catagories that relate to a particular product.  Given that categories are shared across *many* products, you probably want a "master" table of categories as well.

```
select * from categories ; 
+----+------+
| id | name | 
+----+------+
|  1 | Cat1 |
|  2 | Cat1 |
+----+------+

select * from products ; 
+----+--------+-------+-------------+
| id | name   | price | description | 
+----+--------+-------+-------------+
| 11 | Fred   |  1.99 | Flintstone  | 
| 22 | Barney |  2.99 | Rubble      | 
+----+--------+-------+-------------+

select * from prod_cats ; 
+---------+--------+
| prod_id | cat_id | 
+---------+--------+
|      11 |      1 | 
|      22 |      1 | 
|      22 |      2 | 
+---------+--------+
```

To find products with a given category:

```
select p.name 
from       products p 
inner join prod_cats pc 
      on   p.id = pc.prod_id 
inner join categories c 
      on   pc.cat_id = c.id 
where c.name = 'Cat1' 
order by 1 ; 

+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| Barney | 
| Fred   | 
+--------+
```

To find products with *all* given categories:

```
select p.name 
from products p 
where p.id in 
( 
  select pc.prod_id 
  from       prod_cats pc 
  inner join categories c 
        on   pc.cat_id = c.id 
  where c.name in ( 'Cat1', 'Cat2' )   /* Categories to match */ 
  group by pc.prod_id 
  having count( pc.cat_id ) = 2        /* Number of matches required */ 
) t0 
order by 1 ; 

+--------+
| name   |
+--------+
| Barney | 
+--------+
```

Comment: I don't think this is the answer. Rederick already knows he has to create a "link"-table. His question is: how do I move the categories from the "bad" column categories in the products-table to the "good" link-table. So he is asking for a script or stored_procedure to do this normalisation. As it is likely to use cursors and iterations this will depend on the type of rdbms (mysql? sqlserver? oracle? ...)

Comment: he already help me a lot, i made a php script for move all the categories and now is all right